# How can you make RewriteRule with or without / at end

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to make dynamic category pages using RewriteRule, but the problem I face is it works only with ending slash.

This is my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\d\w-]+)/$ category.php?term=$1
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php
```

When I go to http://example.com/category-name it shows 404 error, but when I add slash it works fine.
I am trying to make it so it happens like the following:

> https://example.com/contact -> Exists -> Go to contact.php 
>   https://example.com/category-name -> Exists -> Show category.php?term=category-name 
>   https://example.com/wasdwasd -> Does not exist -> Show 404

Same happens with trailing /.

Comment: You can use the `?` quantifier to make the `/` optional.

Comment: But what you are asking for, does not make much sense to begin with. Your server has no way to determine at this point, that `category-name` is supposed to exist, and `wasdwasd` is not. (Assuming, both don’t actually exist as physical files.) That decision, what is an existing category and what isn’t, should be made by your `category.php` itself then.

Comment: Thank you! Adding `?` somehow fixed my problem.